# My 8080 port says it's allocated when I run Airflow. I ran docker-compose ps and it showed me airflow_airflow-init_1 that has "Exit 0"

Tags: docker-compose, airflow, airflow-webserver

I run "docker logs airflow_airflow-init_1" and get the following result which I don't know how to interprete. I'm new to Airflow. I've already used "netstat -ona | findstr :8080 | findstr LISTENING" to find any processes that are listening and I've killed them.

```
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:339: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
FutureWarning,
The container is run as root user. For security, consider using a regular user account.

/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:339: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
FutureWarning,
DB: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
Performing upgrade with database postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:***@postgres/airflow
[2022-07-15 18:08:21,144] {db.py:1410} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Upgrades done
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:339: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
FutureWarning,
[2022-07-15 18:08:25,045] {manager.py:585} INFO - Removed Permission menu access on 
Permissions to role Admin
[2022-07-15 18:08:25,063] {manager.py:543} INFO - Removed Permission View: menu_access on Permissions
[2022-07-15 18:08:25,117] {manager.py:508} INFO - Created Permission View: menu access on Permissions
[2022-07-15 18:08:25,123] {manager.py:568} INFO - Added Permission menu access on 
Permissions to role Admin
[2022-07-15 18:08:27,292] {providers_manager.py:218} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
[2022-07-15 18:08:28,098] {providers_manager.py:218} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
airflow already exist in the db
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:339: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
  FutureWarning,2.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, seeing `airflow-init_1 exited with code 0` after running `docker-compose up` is [totally expected](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initialize-the-database). It just means airflow has initialized database for you. After its exit, you should see airflow scheduler and airflow webserver up and running.